# What are the flags to be passed to generate ER for 2-3 specific models or even a Single Model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, erd

I am trying to use Railroady gem to create an ER diagram for large Rails application.

With `railroady -C | neato -Tpng > controllers.png` I am able to generate a diagram for all the controllers which is yielding a huge 40mb+ file in pdf or png.

Would like to know the command to generate the Diagram for only selective controllers/models.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `--specify (or -s)` option in order to include only certain files for ER generation as mentioned [in the options of RailRoady's Readme](https://github.com/preston/railroady#options) . As per the readme, this option can be used as `-s, --specify file1[,fileN]`, and it would generate ER for only the files passed as input.
Additionally, in case you need to remove only a few files while generating the ER diagram, you could use the `--exclude file1[,fileN] (--exclude can be replaced with -e as well)` in order to exclude these files while generating the ER diagram.
Also, in case you only want to generate an overview of the schema, which does not contain attributes and methods of each table, you could use the `--brief (or -b)` option.

Comment: Already tried. I just prints the specified model diagram without relationships.